# targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset - wrong proposed offset

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` and it implements `targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset` in order to set paging.  The center item in the `UICollectionView` is the full "large" size, while each other item has a `CGAffineTransformScale` of the "shrunk" scale value.

My problem is that there appears to be an upper limit on the contentOffset so that I can only scroll to item 5 of 7, and it bounces back.  Specifics after the code:

I'm setting the `collectionViewContentSize()` as follows:

```
@IBInspectable var shrunkScale: CGFloat = 0.5 // 0.5 in IB
@IBInspectable var largeSize: CGSize = CGSizeZero // 360x490 in IB
@IBInspectable var itemSpacing: CGFloat = 0 // 32 in IB

var widthPerAdditionalItem: CGFloat {
    return largeSize.width * shrunkScale + itemSpacing
}

override func collectionViewContentSize() -> CGSize {
    guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else {
        return CGSizeZero
    }

    let count = CGFloat(collectionView.numberOfItemsInSection(0))

    let width = largeSize.width + (count) * widthPerAdditionalItem
    let height = collectionView.bounds.height

    let size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)

    return size
}
```

the `targetOffset...` methods reference a single helper method:

```
override func targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset(proposedContentOffset: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {

    let closestPlace = round(proposedContentOffset.x / widthPerAdditionalItem)

    guard let offsetX = offsetXForItemAtIndex(Int(closestPlace)) else {
        return proposedContentOffset
    }
    print("Calculated: \(offsetX), Proposed: \(proposedContentOffset.x), ContentWidth: \(collectionView?.contentSize.width ?? 0 )")
    return CGPoint(x: offsetX, y: proposedContentOffset.y)
}

override func targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset(proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset(proposedContentOffset)
}

func contentOffsetForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGPoint? {
    guard
        let collectionView = self.collectionView,
        let offsetX =  offsetXForItemAtIndex(indexPath.item)
    else {
        return nil
    }
    print("Tap Offset: - \(offsetX) vs. \(collectionView.contentOffset.x)")
    return CGPoint(x: offsetX, y: collectionView.contentOffset.y)

}

private func offsetXForItemAtIndex(index: Int) -> CGFloat? {
    guard
        let count = collectionView?.numberOfItemsInSection(0)
    else {
        return nil
    }

    let proposed =  CGFloat(index) * widthPerAdditionalItem
    let maximum = CGFloat(count) * widthPerAdditionalItem

    // bound min = 0, max = count*width
    return max( min(maximum, proposed), 0)
}
```

Here's What I get:

1. My content Width is `1844.0`
2. I finish dragging the view at offset.x = `1187.5`
3. The `targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset` receives a proposed offset.x = `820.0`
4. I return the "paged" offset.x value of `848.0`
5. The collectionView scrolls to offset.x of `820.0`

What I am expecting:

1. My content Width is `1844.0`
2. I finish dragging the view at offset.x = `1187.5`
3. The `targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset` receives a
   proposed offset.x = `1187.5`
4. I return the "paged" offset.x value of `1272.0`
5. The collectionView scrolls to offset.x of `1272.0`

Debugging:

If I manually call `setContentOffset` with the calculated offset of `1272.0` then it scrolls to the correct position.  But the instant I try to scroll it snaps back to `820.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sitting down and doing some math I figured out the following:

```
contentWidth = 1844
poposedContentOffset.x = 820
1844 - 820 = 1024 // <--- Width of the screen.
```

The content was being displayed from the ***center*** of the screen for the first item, to the ***center*** of the screen for the second item.

This means I needed to add half the collectionView's `frame.width` so the first item can be centered, and half again so the final item could be centered.

The `collectionViewContentSize()` now returns

```
let width = (count-1) * widthPerAdditionalItem + collectionView.bounds.width
let height = collectionView.bounds.height
let size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
```